# Android MaterialDatePicker texts appearing in wrong places

Tags: android, material-ui, datetimepicker

I'm trying to use the MaterialDatePicker (https://material.io/develop/android/components/picker) but the selected date texts and button texts looked different from the examples. My app theme is defined as such: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">`. Thanks in advance!

[image: enter image descriptionenter image description here here]
[image]

Comment: which version of MCD are you using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I'm running 1.3.0-alpha02